# How can I use %TYPE in postgres type definition?

Tags: postgresql

I want to create a type in postgres. And the type of attributes is referring on some table columns. My code:

```sql
CREATE TYPE DomainObj AS 
( DomainID WBXWEBDOMAIN.DOMAINID % TYPE, 
DomainName WBXWEBDOMAIN.DOMAINNAME % TYPE 
);
```

But it reported a syntax error:

```
CREATE  TYPE  DomainObj as (
          DomainID     WBXWEBDOMAIN.DOMAINID%TYPE,
          DomainName   WBXWEBDOMAIN.DOMAINNAME%TYPE
    )
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "%"
LINE 2:           DomainID     WBXWEBDOMAIN.DOMAINID%TYPE,
                                                    ^
```

How to solve this issue?
Must I replace the `%type` with its exact type?

Comment: replacing %type is an easy solution if you are not going to create type again and again.

Comment: Yes. But I am porting my DB from Oracle to PG. My types in Oracle are all created with %type. If I have to replace all of them, it will be very tough.